# How to activate SSD M.2 2260 device 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, ssd, nvme

I have installed a SSD M.2 2260 1TB into my laptop to be used as a secondary SSD eventually to be formatted to XFS. The laptop is a single boot 22.04LTS system, current. The device is listed in the HP BIOS settings as the NVME SSD and I have activated this setting in the laptop BIOS. I have included the output of lspci so the PCIe device does appear to be the NVME memory (Pericom on the SSD M.2 2260).  What do I need to do to activate this device?  My guess is some parameter for the kernel during boot and/or to install a NVME device driver (appropriate commands and/or .deb package for apt would be appreciated).

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
3b:00.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch (rev 05)
3c:01.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch (rev 05)
3c:02.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch (rev 05)
3c:03.0 PCI bridge: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch (rev 05)
3d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
5f:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

As requested, lshw output. However, the output is too large (requires this question to be 33065 characters) and there seems to be no way to attach a plain text file.  I have excerpted the relevant section for the PCIe controller that appears to be associated with the additional SSD (not the primary with a SATA physical interface).  The physical device that plugs into the appropriate "socket" on the motherboard is a SSD M.2 2260 images of which are available on Amazon.

`*-pci:1 description: PCI bridge product: PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch vendor: Pericom Semiconductor physical id: 2 bus info: pci@0000:3c:02.0 version: 05 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list configuration: driver=pcieport resources: iomemory:41310-4130f irq:30 ioport:3000(size=8192) memory:c8000000-cbffffff ioport:4e300000(size=2097152) *-pci:2 description: PCI bridge product: PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch vendor: Pericom Semiconductor physical id: 3 bus info: pci@0000:3c:03.0 version: 05 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list configuration: driver=pcieport resources: iomemory:1f10-1f0f irq:31 memory:cc000000-cc0fffff ioport:4e500000(size=2097152)`

`lscpi -knn` relevant output:
`3c:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch [12d8:2404] (rev 05)

```
DeviceName: WLAN
```

3d:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch [12d8:2404] (rev 05)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
3d:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch [12d8:2404] (rev 05)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
3d:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Pericom Semiconductor PI7C9X2G404 EL/SL PCIe2 4-Port/4-Lane Packet Switch [12d8:2404] (rev 05)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport`

Comment: please edit your question adding the output for `lshw` or `sudo lshw`. information about my nvme only shows with that command and not `lspci`.

Comment: Why would it be NVMe if not directlyl connect to NVMe port? It is a PCIe device. Older model had major issues. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344804/installing-a-pcie-to-pci-reversible-bridge-under-debian-results-in-unclassified

Comment: I have added the relevant `lspci -knn` output to the question body.  How does one map to get to the card as a M.2 SSD?  If this is not possible, the card will be returned.  Also, how does one properly format other than the back-tick enclosure of code?

Comment: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/Compatible-PCIe-NVMe-M-2-SSD-for-HP-ZBOOK-15-G2/td-p/6829303 may be relevant.  Note that the SSD card mentioned is a 2280 physical length form factor, whereas the HP Zbook15 G2 requires a 2260, but otherwise the information in the above URL is correct based upon the HP factory service literature that I have (showing how to install the SSD).  This appears to be PCIe mapped to NVME M.2 SSD.